# Are javascript and css timing synchronized?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, time

Are javascript (timeout, interval) and css (animations, delay) timing synchronized ?

For instance :

```
#anim1 {
animation: anim1 10s linear;
display: none;
}

anim1.style.display = "block" ;
setTimeout(function() {
 anim2.style.webkitAnimation= 'anim2 10s linear';
}, 10000);
```

Will anim2 be *precisely* triggered at the end of anim1 ? Is it different depending on the browser ? In this case I'm more interested in a webkit focus.

Note that anim1 is triggered via javascript to avoid loading time inconsistencies.

**NB** : This is a theoretical question, the above code is an illustration and you must not use it at home as there are way more proper means to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no guarantee. However, there are events which you can listen for;

```
anim1.addEventListener('animationend',function(){
    anim2.style.webkitAnimation= 'anim2 10s linear';
}
```

Note that because these are new, there are still vendor prefixes you need to account for; `webkitAnimationEnd` and `oanimationend` for Webkit and Opera.

Also as my original answer (wrongly) suggested, there is `transitionend` (with similar prefixes) if you want to use CSS transitions instead of animations.

Comment: @Kyslik true, but the best answer I can give to that is "I doubt it". So this is what I would do to solve that particular problem. It's tidier too; the timing can be changed without risking inconsistency.

Comment: I've been looking through the specifications and can't see anything which suggests JavaScript and CSS timing are in any way related. I'd expect it's undefined, but it is an interesting question.

Comment: Thanks, marked as accepted because of the "I doubt it" answer. I'm still surprised of the lack of publication in the wild about this.

Comment: I didn't know that this event exists

Answer (score 2):

This is the wrong way to do this. There isn't any guarantee that they will be in sync, though it's likely they'll be close.

Events are provided for the start, end an repeat of an animation.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/webkitanimationevent details these.

Use code like:

```
element.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", callfunction,false);
```

to bind to it.

Comment: might be good suggest to do this kind of animations but real question is: `Are JavaScript and CSS timing synchronized?`

Comment: Indeed, thanks for your answer but this code was more a theoretical illustration than a real-life example.